# How do I declare multiple exceptions with the @Throws annotation?

Tags: kotlin

A function can be annotated with `@Throws` for a single exception, as follows:

```kotlin
@Throws(NotFoundException::class)
```

How do I declare that my function can throw multiple exceptions (e.g. `NotFoundException` and `NullPointerException`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have understood it. I just have to use a comma to separate different exceptions, as follows:

```kotlin
@Throws(NotFoundException::class, NullPointerException::class)
```